# Is there any more convenient way to insert Math-mode Accents?

Tags: math-mode, equations, accents, shorthands

Is there any more convenient (concise) way to insert Math-mode Accents?
For example is it possible to use a syntax like following:

```
a\^ %instead of \hat{a} 
a\- %instead of \bar{a}
a\~ %instead of \tilde{a}
```

or

```
\^a %instead of \hat{a} 
\-a %instead of \bar{a}
\~a %instead of \tilde{a}
```

Comment: If you do not need the text mode accents you can just go `\let\^\hat` and use `\^` . If you do want `\^` to work as before in text mode then it's a bit trikier (and quite hard to do in a way that will never affect text mode kerns)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by redefining the accent macros only for mathmode, using the `\everymath` and `\everydisplay` token lists. You can do this as follows:

```
% Create a token list for your custom math accent macros
\newtoks\mymathaccents
\mymathaccents={%
  \let\^\hat
  \let\-\bar
  \let\~\tilde
  % etc.
}

% The following adds your custom macros for math accents
% to both inline and displayed math mode 
\everymath=\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
           \expandafter\the\expandafter\everymath\the\mymathaccents} 

\everydisplay=\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
              \expandafter\the\expandafter\everydisplay\the\mymathaccents}
```

This should also preserve the normal meanings of the accent macros for text mode. — Note that for the other part of your question: there is no mechanism to define a new macro to accept an argument which immediately *precedes* it, as in the examples you give.